# Save text files with same name as Excel files

Tags: vba

I have a Visual Basic script that converts excel files to text files.  Let's say I have an excel file called example.xlsx; currently, the script saves it as example.xlsx.txt, which isn't what I want.  I need it to save as: example.txt

Any ideas?

```
Option Explicit

    Dim oFSO, myFolder
Dim xlTXT

myFolder="C:\..."


Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
xlTXT = 21 'Excel TXT format enum
Call ConvertAllExcelFiles(myFolder)
Set oFSO = Nothing

Call MsgBox ("Done!")


Sub ConvertAllExcelFiles(ByVal oFolder)
Dim targetF, oFileList, oFile
Dim oExcel, oWB, oWSH

    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    oExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set targetF = oFSO.GetFolder(oFolder)
    Set oFileList = targetF.Files
    For Each oFile in oFileList
        If (Right(oFile.Name, 4) = "xlsx") Then
            Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
            For Each oWSH in oWB.Sheets
                Call oWSH.SaveAs (oFile.Path & ".txt", xlTXT )
                Exit For
            Next
            Set oWSH = Nothing
            Call oWB.Close
            Set oWB = Nothing
        End If
    Next
    Call oExcel.Quit
    Set oExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Right now you are appending .txt to the end of the file path you need to actually change it seems the easiest way would be `Call oWSH.SaveAs (Replace(oFile.Path,".xlsx" ".txt"), xlTXT )`

Comment: Thanks!  How can I save all the text files into a different folder?

Comment: It looks like you are currently overwriting the file for each worksheet since you are saving each to the same name.  So if a workbook has more than one sheet you will be losing all but the last worksheet.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileSystemObject has a [number of methods](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/05/30/how-can-i-extract-just-the-file-name-from-the-full-path-to-the-file.aspx) such as `GetBaseName`, `GetFileName`. So,

```
Call oWSH.SaveAs (myFolder & "\" & oFile.GetBaseName & ".txt", xlTXT)
```

(`GetFileName` would include the extension.)

But, as Harrison describes, you'll probably want to include the sheetname, or some number, as part of the filename.

You might consider using the worksheets' index as part of the file name, rather than having to invent numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are only saving the first sheet since you are exiting the foreach loop.  To save all the sheets you can

Replace

```
        For Each oWSH in oWB.Sheets
            Call oWSH.SaveAs (oFile.Path & ".txt", xlTXT )
            Exit For
        Next
```

with

```
        For Each oWSH in oWB.Sheets
            Call oWSH.SaveAs (oWB.Name & "_" & oWSH.Name & ".txt", xlTXT )
        Next
```

Note if you wanted to save just the first worksheet instead of using the Exit For after the first sheet you could use this.

```
        Call oWB.Sheets(1).SaveAs (oWB.Name & ".txt", xlTXT )
```